# Streaming RTSP over SSL in iOS (RTSPS)

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, rtsp, libvlc

I have an Rtsp over SSL stream that I want to stream on my iOS app. I'm already using VLC to display rtsp or m3u8 streams no problem, but I can't work out what I need to do to be able to stream rtsps.

Any help appreciated!

to test it, I've tried simply pasting the URL into a desktop version of VLC, but it seems VLC is unable to recognise rtsps. Here are the logs:

```
main debug: starting playback of new item
main debug: resyncing on rtsps://stream-eu1-bravo.dropcam.com:443/sdm_live_stream/CiQA2vuxr9Ami0C1dcP7ZLVcGj-UdCGPuGzmGIg1qNc6hXAJKK8ScQBMPhenrjd8wVuFEdZCQxSAGpHB2nM0ofPXdAf4ScFtq9OlXc5T3zibW981-SU9R0W8WdTsHWFxpCbpFj034mB6-UB9PWJ7h-kx4eoXvIbL8LSYSsDWubg5Jla7AiKVgafv_MyYJ572zgWPm5e-tNj6
main debug: rtsps://stream-eu1-bravo.dropcam.com:443/sdm_live_stream/CiQA2vuxr9Ami0C1dcP7ZLVcGj-UdCGPuGzmGIg1qNc6hXAJKK8ScQBMPhenrjd8wVuFEdZCQxSAGpHB2nM0ofPXdAf4ScFtq9OlXc5T3zibW981-SU9R0W8WdTsHWFxpCbpFj034mB6-UB9PWJ7h-kx4eoXvIbL8LSYSsDWubg5Jla7AiKVgafv_MyYJ572zgWPm5e-tNj6 is at 1
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'rtsps://stream-eu1-bravo.dropcam.com:443/sdm_live_stream/CiQA2vuxr9Ami0C1dcP7ZLVcGj-UdCGPuGzmGIg1qNc6hXAJKK8ScQBMPhenrjd8wVuFEdZCQxSAGpHB2nM0ofPXdAf4ScFtq9OlXc5T3zibW981-SU9R0W8WdTsHWFxpCbpFj034mB6-UB9PWJ7h-kx4eoXvIbL8LSYSsDWubg5Jla7AiKVgafv_MyYJ572zgWPm5e-tNj6'
main debug: requesting art for new input thread
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
main debug: using default timeshift path
main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
main debug: `rtsps://stream-eu1-bravo.dropcam.com:443/sdm_live_stream/CiQA2vuxr9Ami0C1dcP7ZLVcGj-UdCGPuGzmGIg1qNc6hXAJKK8ScQBMPhenrjd8wVuFEdZCQxSAGpHB2nM0ofPXdAf4ScFtq9OlXc5T3zibW981-SU9R0W8WdTsHWFxpCbpFj034mB6-UB9PWJ7h-kx4eoXvIbL8LSYSsDWubg5Jla7AiKVgafv_MyYJ572zgWPm5e-tNj6?auth=g.0.eyJraWQiOiIyMzhiNTUxZmMyM2EyM2Y4M2E2ZTE3MmJjZTg0YmU3ZjgxMzAzMmM4IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJuZXN0X2lkOm5lc3QtcGhvZW5peC1wcm9kOjk4MTkzNTgiLCJpc3MiOiJuZXN0LXNlY3VyaXR5LWF1dGhwcm94eSIsInBvbCI6IjNwLW9hdXRoLXNjb3BlLUFQSV9TRE1fU0VSVklDRS1jbGllbnQtNjU0ODMyODQ2NzI0LTdvMGw2anVjZ25icjYzYmRiaWJnNGV1YmhoZnY5NzJ1LmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjAwOTYwODU5fQ.Un7jfeIbnXBeW-V41vN8Hh7V7_8AZIC_cnkHMS2kxSniRDRPArQFGpTgHVWj9uXNoqKohuckZW-g_k3KLXACYStUp2ONRXrw0qKPIGfm-BuWc8WrmdihGpon1qBkZ5PIT84w0_IEUgu8SrjuewMWmp1xRWD_zcW9zeVSmA1L4Gpa8z3JHAJoi4hIz5qCKN2e8cGNBq06VsOwEAtspxOqj2xIiyRFI34wwutFW07yjBm_meIm5abRJS7I-YIH56j0vQEdOI55amj3XnKzSaBJPU7e83mJhGYuhfHHJaI1N6lX1IuZdTwQuZ9RXhFrSeDqnriarsrQIt6Z4Qs8ZkYiEQ' gives access `rtsps' demux `any' path `stream-eu1-bravo.dropcam.com:443/sdm_live_stream/CiQA2vuxr9Ami0C1dcP7ZLVcGj-UdCGPuGzmGIg1qNc6hXAJKK8ScQBMPhenrjd8wVuFEdZCQxSAGpHB2nM0ofPXdAf4ScFtq9OlXc5T3zibW981-SU9R0W8WdTsHWFxpCbpFj034mB6-UB9PWJ7h-kx4eoXvIbL8LSYSsDWubg5Jla7AiKVgafv_MyYJ572zgWPm5e-tNj6?auth=g.0.eyJraWQiOiIyMzhiNTUxZmMyM2EyM2Y4M2E2ZTE3MmJjZTg0YmU3ZjgxMzAzMmM4IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJuZXN0X2lkOm5lc3QtcGhvZW5peC1wcm9kOjk4MTkzNTgiLCJpc3MiOiJuZXN0LXNlY3VyaXR5LWF1dGhwcm94eSIsInBvbCI6IjNwLW9hdXRoLXNjb3BlLUFQSV9TRE1fU0VSVklDRS1jbGllbnQtNjU0ODMyODQ2NzI0LTdvMGw2anVjZ25icjYzYmRiaWJnNGV1YmhoZnY5NzJ1LmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjAwOTYwODU5fQ.Un7jfeIbnXBeW-V41vN8Hh7V7_8AZIC_cnkHMS2kxSniRDRPArQFGpTgHVWj9uXNoqKohuckZW-g_k3KLXACYStUp2ONRXrw0qKPIGfm-BuWc8WrmdihGpon1qBkZ5PIT84w0_IEUgu8SrjuewMWmp1xRWD_zcW9zeVSmA1L4Gpa8z3JHAJoi4hIz5qCKN2e8cGNBq06VsOwEAtspxOqj2xIiyRFI34wwutFW07yjBm_meIm5abRJS7I-YIH56j0vQEdOI55amj3XnKzSaBJPU7e83mJhGYuhfHHJaI1N6lX1IuZdTwQuZ9RXhFrSeDqnriarsrQIt6Z4Qs8ZkYiEQ'
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Users/PaulNeedler/Library/Application Support/org.videolan.vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
main debug: creating demux: access='rtsps' demux='any' location='stream-eu1-bravo.dropcam.com:443/sdm_live_stream/CiQA2vuxr9Ami0C1dcP7ZLVcGj-UdCGPuGzmGIg1qNc6hXAJKK8ScQBMPhenrjd8wVuFEdZCQxSAGpHB2nM0ofPXdAf4ScFtq9OlXc5T3zibW981-SU9R0W8WdTsHWFxpCbpFj034mB6-UB9PWJ7h-kx4eoXvIbL8LSYSsDWubg5Jla7AiKVgafv_MyYJ572zgWPm5e-tNj6?auth=g.0.eyJraWQiOiIyMzhiNTUxZmMyM2EyM2Y4M2E2ZTE3MmJjZTg0YmU3ZjgxMzAzMmM4IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJuZXN0X2lkOm5lc3QtcGhvZW5peC1wcm9kOjk4MTkzNTgiLCJpc3MiOiJuZXN0LXNlY3VyaXR5LWF1dGhwcm94eSIsInBvbCI6IjNwLW9hdXRoLXNjb3BlLUFQSV9TRE1fU0VSVklDRS1jbGllbnQtNjU0ODMyODQ2NzI0LTdvMGw2anVjZ25icjYzYmRiaWJnNGV1YmhoZnY5NzJ1LmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjAwOTYwODU5fQ.Un7jfeIbnXBeW-V41vN8Hh7V7_8AZIC_cnkHMS2kxSniRDRPArQFGpTgHVWj9uXNoqKohuckZW-g_k3KLXACYStUp2ONRXrw0qKPIGfm-BuWc8WrmdihGpon1qBkZ5PIT84w0_IEUgu8SrjuewMWmp1xRWD_zcW9zeVSmA1L4Gpa8z3JHAJoi4hIz5qCKN2e8cGNBq06VsOwEAtspxOqj2xIiyRFI34wwutFW07yjBm_meIm5abRJS7I-YIH56j0vQEdOI55amj3XnKzSaBJPU7e83mJhGYuhfHHJaI1N6lX1IuZdTwQuZ9RXhFrSeDqnriarsrQIt6Z4Qs8ZkYiEQ' file='(null)'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "rtsps": 14 candidates
main debug: no access_demux modules matched
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lua/meta/fetcher
main debug: creating access: rtsps://stream-eu1-bravo.dropcam.com:443/sdm_live_stream/CiQA2vuxr9Ami0C1dcP7ZLVcGj-UdCGPuGzmGIg1qNc6hXAJKK8ScQBMPhenrjd8wVuFEdZCQxSAGpHB2nM0ofPXdAf4ScFtq9OlXc5T3zibW981-SU9R0W8WdTsHWFxpCbpFj034mB6-UB9PWJ7h-kx4eoXvIbL8LSYSsDWubg5Jla7AiKVgafv_MyYJ572zgWPm5e-tNj6?auth=g.0.eyJraWQiOiIyMzhiNTUxZmMyM2EyM2Y4M2E2ZTE3MmJjZTg0YmU3ZjgxMzAzMmM4IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJuZXN0X2lkOm5lc3QtcGhvZW5peC1wcm9kOjk4MTkzNTgiLCJpc3MiOiJuZXN0LXNlY3VyaXR5LWF1dGhwcm94eSIsInBvbCI6IjNwLW9hdXRoLXNjb3BlLUFQSV9TRE1fU0VSVklDRS1jbGllbnQtNjU0ODMyODQ2NzI0LTdvMGw2anVjZ25icjYzYmRiaWJnNGV1YmhoZnY5NzJ1LmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjAwOTYwODU5fQ.Un7jfeIbnXBeW-V41vN8Hh7V7_8AZIC_cnkHMS2kxSniRDRPArQFGpTgHVWj9uXNoqKohuckZW-g_k3KLXACYStUp2ONRXrw0qKPIGfm-BuWc8WrmdihGpon1qBkZ5PIT84w0_IEUgu8SrjuewMWmp1xRWD_zcW9zeVSmA1L4Gpa8z3JHAJoi4hIz5qCKN2e8cGNBq06VsOwEAtspxOqj2xIiyRFI34wwutFW07yjBm_meIm5abRJS7I-YIH56j0vQEdOI55amj3XnKzSaBJPU7e83mJhGYuhfHHJaI1N6lX1IuZdTwQuZ9RXhFrSeDqnriarsrQIt6Z4Qs8ZkYiEQ
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/fetcher
main debug: looking for access module matching "rtsps": 23 candidates
main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
main debug: no access modules matched
main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Users/PaulNeedler/Library/Application Support/org.videolan.vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lua/meta/art
main debug: dead input
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
main debug: no art finder modules matched
main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Users/PaulNeedler/Library/Application Support/org.videolan.vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lua/meta/fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/fetcher
main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Users/PaulNeedler/Library/Application Support/org.videolan.vlc/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
main debug: no art finder modules matched
main debug: changing item without a request (current 1/2)
main debug: nothing to play
main debug: exiting
main debug: removing all interfaces
main debug: removing module "macosx"
macosx debug: Closing macosx interface
macosx debug: applicationWillTerminate called
macosx debug: Playback has been ended
macosx debug: Deinitializing input manager
macosx debug: Deinitializing VLCMain object
macosx debug: Deinitializing extensions manager
macosx debug: Deinitializing playlist model
macosx debug: Deinitializing dialog provider
macosx debug: Deinitializing main menu
main debug: removing module "hotkeys"
main debug: destroying
main debug: deactivating the playlist
main debug: removing module "auhal"
main debug: saving media library to file /Users/PaulNeedler/Library/Application Support/org.videolan.vlc/ml.xspf.tmp55490
main debug: looking for playlist export module matching "export-xspf": 4 candidates
main debug: using playlist export module "export"
main debug: removing module "export"
main debug: deleting item `Media Library'
main debug: deleting item `rtsps://stream-eu1-bravo.dropcam.com:443/sdm_live_stream/CiQA2vuxr9Ami0C1dcP7ZLVcGj-UdCGPuGzmGIg1qNc6hXAJKK8ScQBMPhenrjd8wVuFEdZCQxSAGpHB2nM0ofPXdAf4ScFtq9OlXc5T3zibW981-SU9R0W8WdTsHWFxpCbpFj034mB6-UB9PWJ7h-kx4eoXvIbL8LSYSsDWubg5Jla7AiKVgafv_MyYJ572zgWPm5e-tNj6'
main debug: deleting item `rtsps://stream-eu1-bravo.dropcam.com:443'
main debug: deleting item `Playlist'
main debug: removing module "memory"
-- logger module stopped --
```

Comment: can you share logs please?

Comment: Also, your code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve